# Site Column Page Not Accessible

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I accidentally created a field type called "Test" instead of Text using the following

Powershell command:

Get site and web object

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://mysite/sites/.."
$web = $site.RootWeb 

#Assign fieldXML variable with XML string for site column
$fieldXML = '<Field Type="Test"...etc.
```

Poweshell threw the following error:

> Exception calling "AddFieldAsXml" with
>   "1" argument(s): "Field type Test is
>   not installed properly. Go to the 
>   list settings page to delete this
>   field. " At
>   C:\Scripts\addsitecolumn.ps1:25
>   char:26
>   + $web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml <<<< ($fieldXML) 
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
>   MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Is there a Powershell command to delete the Test Field or is there a way to get to this fields 'hidded' page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in PowerShell:

```
$web1 = Get-SPWeb "http://testWeb"
$field = $web1.Fields["Test 1"]
$field.Delete()
```

"Test 1" is the Display name of the field you tried to add earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem today.  I ran Sharepoint Manager 2010 and got the SchemaXML off from the site collection and found out that there were 3 site columns with nothing defined in it.   I tried to remove it by powershell above with display name (which is "") or index, but none of that work as the item object see it as null.  Then I came across this post:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11945/error-message-field-type-publishing-image-is-not-installed-properly-go-to-the

Which remove it from the content database and that worked for me.  Right after that I check the SchemaXML and the 3 strange site columns were removed.  It's interesting how the content type table ties directly into this problem.